# run jquery code on loaded page via jquery ajax request (load)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading an entire middle div via JQuery Ajax call and I simply want to run $(document).ready on the loaded page

header.php loads part of the page

```
var $next = $("<div class='nextab center'>").insertAfter('#content .current');
        $next.load($this.attr('href')+ ' #content .center section' , function(resp) { ...
```

}

so for example when header.php loads career.php it does not run all the code that is inside the $(document).ready(function(){ that is on career.php

I was thinking of creating a function init on each page loaded but not sure how to call this function from the load callback

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the efforts you've made.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function YourActionOnDocumentReady(){
   // write whatever you want to do     
}
```

And in document ready call the above function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    YourActionOnDocumentReady();
});
```

And use ajaxStop function to run the same code

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
     YourActionOnDocumentReady();
});
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Have you tried the code..? If it worked for you dont forget to mark as  answer

Comment: Dont refresh the page using f5 or hitting enter on address bar, as it wont be a ajax call.. Try clicking on "about" tab and then your ajaxStop will run.. And I can see that It is working perfectly

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to say.. I hitted your URL directly and after that I tried Each tab.. It is showing the alert message perfectly in every tab.. I think you should clear your browser cache and then retry again...

Comment: Why dont you directly call the init function in ajaxStop? It wont harm anything...

Comment: Yes I can see the alert('ajax code done'); everytime too but the init function is not called in this case  , the init function is on the what new page  / you are not seeing the alert('call init function'); right? when starting in the about page then click on the what new tab

Comment: Alternatively you can add a else block to your code and copy paste the content of document ready in the "else" block....

Comment: As I am observing It is not showing the alert but the Init is running... "Loading" image is being shown... And All the animations you expect are running well...

Comment: no actually in the what_new page there is a dropdown menu that is initialized in the document ready of this page , when the init function is not called the dropdown functionality is not working

Comment: ok so finally it's working thanks to you ! here is what i did / i created a js file with all the jquery code for all pages http://leasabba.www63.a2hosting.com/leonarddev/js/main.js  I just add the link to this js in the header.php and it works just fine now THANKS again (Let me know what you think of this solution )